# No ConstraintLayout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I learning on how to build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout by following this  [article](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project). But I can't see ConstraintLayout options in my Android Project.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tony.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

[image]

What did I miss here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConstraintLayout is available in an API library that's compatible with Android 2.3 (API level 9) and higher. This page provides a guide to building a layout with **ConstraintLayout in Android Studio 2.3 or higher**.

[Build responsive UI with ContraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project)

As you are using an older version of android studio first upgrade your Android-studio version.

Comment: But I'm using API 23

Comment: @JohnJoe, Minimum requirement for android studio is 2.3

Comment: @Maddy does it mean that if I setup the minimum sdk version in the manifest to api 9, I'll still be able to use it without any issue, or do i need to use some sort of backward support library?

Comment: @YonatanNir, it is not mentioned in docs for minimum support, but I think you can do it. I wondered that a device with API level 9 still exists :D

Comment: @Maddy but the point is that its not a part of the support AppCompat library? I just wonder how it can work on API 9 if its not a part of it

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your Android Studio to 2.2 or above. Constraint layout was introduced in [Android Studio 2.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#2-2-0).  It is always recommended to use latest version of Android Studio.